# Eclipse does not remember external source attachments

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-kepler

Using Eclipse 4.3.1 (Kepler) on Ubuntu, I find that each time I exit and reenter Eclipse, I have to respecify my external source attachments. What is the key to making Eclipse remember them?

1. Open the Source Attachment Configuration dialog by clicking on the "Change Attached Source" button in the Class File Editor; or open the similar Java Source Attachment dialog by right-clicking on the containing jar in Package Explorer and selecting "Properties".

   I've tried both.
2. In the dialog, click on the "External File" button and navigate to a jar containing sources, or click on the "External Folder" button and navigate to a directory containing .java files in subdirectories corresponding to the package hierarchy.

All these ways work until I quit Eclipse and come back in.

Comment: Add the exact steps how you attach the sources in your question.

Comment: 1. Open the Source Attachment Configuration dialog by clicking on the "Change Attached Source" button in the Class File Editor; or open the similar Java Source Attachment dialog by right-clicking on the containing jar in Package Explorer and selecting "Properties". I've tried both.  
  
2. In the dialog, click on the "External File" button and navigate to a jar containing sources, or click on the "External Folder" button and navigate to a directory containing .java files in subdirectories corresponding to the package hierarchy.  
  
All these ways work until I quit Eclipse and come back in.

Comment: Please edit the original question instead of cramming this complex information into a comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have never used these parts of Eclipse; I'm using Maven to manage my dependencies and Maven will automatically attach sources - so take my answer with a grain of salt :-)

I'm not sure why Eclipse doesn't remember those settings. My current feeling is that those settings are temporary.

If you edit the source attachments in the project's properties (look for "Java Build Path"; there is a tab "Libraries"), then the changes should be saved in the file `.classpath`. Have a look in there.

Lastly, you can try to create a "User Library" (search for this term in the preferences dialog). Here, you can define a bundle of JARs which make up some library. After adding the code JAR, you get options to specify the source JAR.